# Почему регулярное выражение не выделяет текст?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему [данное регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/aTsNPK/1) не выделяет `String3` и `String4` во вторую группу захвата?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так:

```
/^(?!v_).*$/gm
```